# Font used in Stewart's Calculus

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Does anyone know what's the font used in Stewart's Calculus? [image]

Comment: It sure looks like a Times Roman clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated)

The text is Times (the Adobe/Linotype version, not Monotype’s Times New Roman (which, despite the name is the original)). The symbols are mostly the Adobe Mathematical Pi font.

Stewart’s *Calculus* is not set with TeX/LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a style of this type in `pdfLaTeX` (too long for a complete comment).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\makeatletter
\def\upintkern@{\mkern-7mu\mathchoice{\mkern-3.5mu}{}{}{}}
\def\upintdots@{\mathchoice{\mkern-4mu\@cdots\mkern-4mu}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}\mkern1.5mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}%
 {{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}\mkern1mu{\cdotp}}}
\newcommand{\upiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{2}}
\newcommand{\upiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{3}}
\newcommand{\upiiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{4}}
\newcommand{\upidotsint}{\DOTSI\protect\UpMultiIntegral{0}}
\newcommand{\UpMultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\upintop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\upintdots@\else\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\tw@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\thr@@\noexpand\upintop\noexpand\upintkern@\fi
    \noexpand\upintop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [1]  mdbchr7v }{}%old 0.8
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [1]  mdbchb7v }{}%old 0.8
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{uplargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{82}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointop}{\mathop}{uplargesymbols}{"48}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDB}{}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{MDB}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchrmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}{ <->s * [0.8]  mdbchbmb }{}
\DeclareFontShape{MDB}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MDB}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{MDB}{mdbch}{m}{n}%
\SetSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{bold}{MDB}{mdbch}{b}{n}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upintclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{128}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upointctrclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{132}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{134}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upoiiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{136}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\upint}{\DOTSI\upintop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\upoint}{\DOTSI\upointop\ilimits@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[ \upiint\limits_S \sum^{n}_{i=1}{}\partial \]
\end{document}
```